# Are there any online competitions for Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, kaggle

Kaggle is limited to only supervised learning problems. There used to be www.rl-competition.org but they've stopped.

Is there anything else I can do other than locally trying out different algorithms for various RL problems?

Comment: If only you asked a few weeks ago! AWS DeepRacer Challenge on Udacity ended recently. But if you never used AWS before, I think you get some free credit (30 or 100 USD) once you open your account, and you can try out DeepRacer yourself. https://www.udacity.com/aws-deepracer-scholarship

Comment: You could try using a Reinforcement Learning approach in an appropriate "Supervised" Kaggle competition, to beat other people that are using a purely Supervised ML approach. If you win, you'll get exposure in the winners blog and you can talk about your use of RL. And if you don't win, you could share your notebook publicly and inspire others, start discussions and even get points on your notebook that go towards your ranking (notebook ranking, but still, ranking).
Good luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: Kaggle is not limited to SL problems. There are some problems that can also be solved with RL.

Answer (score 5):

AICrowd has numerous challenges in the domain, with some very interesting challenges running currently. Here is a short list:

- https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges?&categories=reinforcement-learning (Complete list with RL tag)
- https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/neurips-2020-procgen-competition
- https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/neurips-2020-flatland-challenge
- https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/neurips-2019-minerl-competition

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

There's a list of ongoing and past RL competitions [here](https://github.com/seungjaeryanlee/awesome-rl-competitions). The ongoing competitions according to that list are

- [AWS DeepRacer League](https://aws.amazon.com/deepracer/league/)
- [Connect X](https://www.kaggle.com/c/connectx)
- [GOSEEK Challenge](https://github.com/MIT-TESSE/goseek-challenge)

Answer (score 3):

Kaggle recently started adding 'Simulation' competitions, which are well-suited for reinforcement learning.

The first competition that's live (no prizes) is [ConnectX](https://www.kaggle.com/c/connectx), like a generalised Connect Four.

The first competition with prize money is likely to be the next iteration of TwoSigma's Halite. There's a page for it here, but it hasn't been launched yet: https://www.kaggle.com/c/halite/overview

I created a site that lists [ongoing machine learning competitions including Reinforcement Learning competitions](https://mlcontests.com/) - you can also sign up to the email list in case you want to get emails (roughly monthly) when new competitions launch. As of right now (May 2020) there are a few live RL competitions on there - the KDD cup, and AWS DeepRacer.

Answer (score 2):

OpenAI has [leaderboards](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Leaderboard) for their gym-environments, if you want to compete with other people on runtime and efficiency.

Comment: I guess this works too. But I was looking for something like Kaggle, just centered around RL.